# How do I use JavaScript for find out style values set with STYLE tag and not with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

In a web page I've made, I've used a style block to define position: absolute for a particular id. I also set the top and left items too. This all works fine.

```
<style>
#vPage { position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; }
</style>
```

But when I try to *read* the value using Javascript:
obj.style.position

```
alert(document.getElementById("vPage").style.position);
```

Its value is ""

Why is that? How can I check the style of a page element that was set with the style tag and **not** set with Javascript *FROM* Javascript?

The browser I'm using is IE7. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/. Oh, and this is just another reason to use jQuery ;)

Comment: Why not make this an answer, @j08691? Looks like an answer to me, along with a simple "the style property will only give you values for inline style" and maybe the snippet that will work for IE7.

Comment: @Orville: You're looking for the *computed* style of an element. And of course there's a standard way and an IE way. The link above is also the one I stumbled upon and was going to post.

Comment: @GregPettit - I just felt like I'd be copy/pasting someone else's work when a link would suffice.

Comment: @j08691 Noble intention! You'd still put the link, though. Nobody would fault you for pointing to someone else's existing work as an answer. We do it all the time! Blog posts aren't any more sacred than online API documentation, as long as you give credit where it's due. ;-) Just think you deserve the points for finding the answer is all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following function to get the styles across the browsers, el=your element id and cssprop=any style prop

```
function getStyle(el, cssprop){
 if (el.currentStyle) //IE
  return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
 else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //Firefox
  return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
 else //try and get inline style
  return el.style[cssprop]
}
```

Comment: I know, I know! NOW I am checking this!  I've been way too passive using StackOverflow... which by the way I think is the best site out there for users to get answers for tech questions. I hope to do better going forward.